# Nunit Testing with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller, nunit, moq

I recently started learning Unit Test in MVC and used NUnit Framework for Test Cases. My problem is, i cannot understand for what should i write Test case. Imagine i have CRUD operation and i want to Test them, so what should be my Test case condition.

Here is my Interface class:

```
public interface IUserRepository 
{ 
    //Creating Single User Records into database using EF.
    bool CreateUser(tbl_Users objUser);

    //Updating Single User Records into database using EF.
    void UpdateUser(tbl_Users objUser);

    //Deleting Single User Records from database using EF.
    bool DeleteUser(long IdUser);
}
```

Here is my Repository Class:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    DBContext objDBContext = new DBContext();      

    /// <summary>
    /// Creating new User Record into Database
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="objUser"></param>
    public bool CreateUser(tbl_Users objUser)
    {
        bool blnResult = false;
        objUser.MiddleName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(objUser.MiddleName) ? string.Empty : objUser.MiddleName.Trim();
        objUser.Photo = string.Empty;
        objUser.Approved = false;
        objUser.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        objUser.DeleteFlag = false;
        objUser.UpdBy = 0;
        objUser.UpdDate = DateTime.Now;
        objDBContext.tbl_Users.Add(objUser);
        blnResult = Convert.ToBoolean(objDBContext.SaveChanges());
        return blnResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updating existing User Record into Database
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="objUser"></param>
    public void UpdateUser(tbl_Users objUser)
    {
        objUser.MiddleName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(objUser.MiddleName) ? string.Empty : objUser.MiddleName.Trim();
        objUser.Approved = true;
        objUser.UpdBy = objUser.IdUser;
        objUser.UpdDate = DateTime.Now;
        objDBContext.Entry(objUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
        objDBContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deleting existing User Record from Database
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="IdUser"></param>
    public bool DeleteUser(long IdUser)
    {
        bool blnResult = false;
        tbl_Users objUser = objDBContext.tbl_Users.Where(x => x.IdUser == IdUser).Single();
        objUser.ConfirmPassword = objUser.Password;
        objUser.UpdDate = DateTime.Now;
        objUser.DeleteFlag = true;
        blnResult = Convert.ToBoolean(objDBContext.SaveChanges());
        return blnResult;
    }        
}
```

And Here is My Controller class

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    tbl_Users objUser = new tbl_Users();
    UserRepository Repository = new UserRepository();        

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(tbl_Users objUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                Repository.CreateUser(objUser);
                return RedirectToAction("Update", "User");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        return View();
    }       

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(tbl_Users objUser)
    {
        Repository.UpdateUser(objUser);
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Delete(long IdUser = 0)
    {
        bool blnResult = Repository.DeleteUser(IdUser);
        if (blnResult)
        {
            return View("Delete");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are Test cases which i tried to Execute using Moq

```
[TestFixture]
public class UserControllerTest
{
    UserController Controller;

    [SetUp]
    public void Initialise()
    {
        Controller = new UserController();
    }       

    [Test]
    public void DeleteTest()
    {
        var ObjUser = new Mock<IUserRepository>();

        ObjUser.Setup(X => X.DeleteUser(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(true);

        var Result = ObjUser.Object.DeleteUser(1);
        Assert.That(Result, Is.True);
    }        

    [Test]
    public void CreateTest()
    {
        tbl_Users User = new tbl_Users();
        Mock<IUserRepository> MockIUserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        MockIUserRepository.Setup(X => X.CreateUser(It.IsAny<tbl_Users>())).Returns(true);

        var Result = MockIUserRepository.Object.CreateUser(User);

        Assert.That(Result, Is.True);
    }         

    [TearDown]
    public void DeInitialise()
    {
        Controller = null;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me, how to Write test cases for above Controller Action Method with brief description about test cases using Moq.

Answer (score 3):

you have a couple of problems. the first is that you have not tested your controller, you have tested your mock. The second is that your controller creates it's own user repository. this means that you can't provide a mock user repository in order to test, even if you were testing it.

The solution to the first on is to test the controller, by calling its methods and asserting the results, however you'll have solve the second one before you can do that in your tests.

To solve the second one you'll need to apply the [dependency inversion principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and pass your `IUserRepository` implementation into your controller (via the constructor ideally).

you could change your controller to have a constructor like this:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    tbl_Users objUser = new tbl_Users();
    IUserRepository Repository; 

    public UserController(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
         Repository = userRepository;
    }   

    ...etc    
}
```

then you can change your tests to be more like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UserControllerTest
{ 
    [Test]
    public void DeleteTest()
    {
        var ObjUser = new Mock<IUserRepository>();

        ObjUser.Setup(X => X.DeleteUser(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(true);

        var Result = new UserController(ObjUser.Object).Delete(1);
        Assert.That(Result, //is expected view result with expected model);
        Assert.That(ObjUser.Verify(), Is.True);        
    }        

    [Test]
    public void CreateTest()
    {
        tbl_Users User = new tbl_Users();
        Mock<IUserRepository> MockIUserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        MockIUserRepository.Setup(X => X.CreateUser(It.IsAny<tbl_Users>())).Returns(true);

        var Result = var Result = new UserController(ObjUser.Object).Create(User);;

        Assert.That(Result, //is a view result with expected view model);
        Assert.That(ObjUser.Verify(), Is.True); 
    }         
}
```

now you are testing the actual controller and checking it returns the right view and that it interacts with the mock repository in the expected way

Comment: There are so many Compilation Error in Test cases you wrote above.. and what does "//is a view result with expected view model" this means in Assert, is it a comment or something i need to replace with

Comment: yes, the code is not meant to compile (I'm not writing it in the IDE, just in the web page and my recollection of exactly which methods to use migth be a little bit off), but to guide you as to what the problems are. if you are calling the Delete method of your controller, this returns an `ActionResult`, but in the case of Delete it will actually be a `ViewResult` instance, so your test needs to verify that the `ActionResult` that is returned is actually a `ViewResult` instance and that it has the expected view model